# Nagios-XI: what ARGS to use for USEDDISKSPACE on 100GB C drive

Tags: nagios

I keep getting Nagios XI alerts that say:

> (PROBLEM Service Alert)
>   Hostname.domain.com Address: 192.168.x.x. State: CRITICAL Info: C:\ -
>   total: 99.9 Gb - usedService: Drive C: Disk usage Host:

...but here's the thing, the C:\ drive is only about 63% full. How can I make Nagios XI actually do the check correctly? Here's what I currently have under Nagios CCM > Services:

$ARG1$ (password to NSclient)
$ARG2$ USEDDISKSPACE
**$ARG3$ -l C -w 95 -c 9**

Despite all my googling, I can't figure out what these ARG3 values mean, or if they are right. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Never mind I guess, I found this: https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-and-Systems-Management/check_disk_space/details

Comment: That link is for one potential disk space checking script, but it isn't the only one of many, and that particular script seems to be for *nix machines, so I doubt it is the plugin you are using.  You are probably using one of the examples that came with nsclient.

Comment: Yes, the NSClient++, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ARG3$ -l C -w 95 -c 9` is a typo.  It means warning (-w) is at 95% full, and critical (-c) is at 9% full.

You want `$ARG3$ -l C -w 95 -c 98`, or something like that.  Replace the -w and -c numbers with ones that make sense in your environment.  (For 100GB, I'd drop them down to -w 90 -c 95 at least.)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out what these ARG3 values mean

You need to look at the script/binary that is defined in your nsclient configuration.  Keep in mind that by default nsclient doesn't even accept arguments for security reasons.  Since arguments can possibly be abused to remotely hack your monitored server (`allow arguments = false`).  You may need to manually make these changes in the nsclient configuration on the system you are monitoring.

Comment: Thanks, @Zoredache. This worked for ARG3: -l C -w 85 -c 95